# jQuery not working when i load my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to dim the rest of the page when i hover my menu. But my jQuery code is not running, is not firing up when i hover the menu. Can somebody help me? Thank you.

This part is with problems :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
                $('#meniu').hover(function(){
                        $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 1);
                    }, function(){
                        $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                });
   </script>
```

Comment: Well my whole code is having some weird bevahiour. I will add the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this .its working fine

```
<div id="meniu">asfdasf</div>
   <p id="TINT">fdsafdsaf</p>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $('#meniu').hover(function(){
                        $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 1);
                    }, function(){
                        $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#meniu').hover(function(){
                $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 1);
            }, function(){
                $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`script` tag is the problem .don't include the js function inside the linked script tag inside .add separate tags in both

```js
$('#meniu').hover(function() {
  $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 1);
}, function() {
  $('#TINT').fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="meniu">menu</p>
  <p id="TINT" style="display:none"> TINT  </p>
```